Problem sales analysis-Leet Code Question 1070
Here's the problem statement
Write a solution to select the product id, year, quantity, and price for the first year of every product sold.
Input:
Sales table:
+---------+------------+------+----------+-------+
| sale_id | product_id | year | quantity | price |
+---------+------------+------+----------+-------+ 
| 1       | 100        | 2008 | 10       | 5000  |
| 2       | 100        | 2009 | 12       | 5000  |
| 7       | 200        | 2011 | 15       | 9000  |
+---------+------------+------+----------+-------+
Product table:
+------------+--------------+
| product_id | product_name |
+------------+--------------+
| 100        | Nokia        |
| 200        | Apple        |
| 300        | Samsung      |
+------------+--------------+
Output: 
+------------+------------+----------+-------+
| product_id | first_year | quantity | price |
+------------+------------+----------+-------+ 
| 100        | 2008       | 10       | 5000  |
| 200        | 2011       | 15       | 9000  |
+------------+------------+----------+-------+

My solution
    select product_id, min(year) as first_year, quantity, price from Sales 
    GROUP BY product_id;

How is this solution incomplete and why does this query pass 1 test case and fails the rest?

min() only finds the minimum year.  it has no effect on which quantity and price are returned.  with the highly recommended (and default for a long time now) ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY setting you will get an error from this query.  without that setting, it will pick an arbitrary quantity and price to return from the rows for each product.

"How is this solution incomplete" - did you check what it returns?

You could use a correlated subquery (in Where clause) to filter the first year per product:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  sales (sale_id, product_id, year, quantity, price ) AS 
    ( Select  1, 100, 2008, 10, 5000  Union All
      Select  2, 100, 2009, 12, 5000  Union All
      Select  7, 200, 2011, 15, 9000  
    ),
  products (product_id, product_name ) AS
    ( Select 100, 'Nokia'     Union All
      Select 200, 'Apple'     Union All
      Select 300, 'Samsung'
    )

--      S Q L :
Select s.product_id, s.year as first_year, s.quantity, s.price
From   sales s
Where  s.year = ( Select Min(year) From sales Where product_id = s.product_id ) 

/*    R e s u l t : 
product_id  first_year  quantity    price
----------  ----------  --------  -------
       100        2008        10     5000
       200        2011        15     9000    */

See the fiddle here.

How is this solution incomplete and why does this query pass 1 test case and fails the rest?

Your sql ends with the error: "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column ..."
The standard sql rule is that one and only one row should be fetched per Group By column(s). Consequencialy, that requiers all nonaggregated columns from selection list to be listed in Group By clause ...

Well first of all, the query you just posted is not correct. Because here in this query:
select product_id, min(year) as first_year, quantity, price from sale
GROUP BY product_id;

You are trying to print out quantity and price after applying group by which is not possible. Because this is not how group by works, It is gonna split your whole table into smaller iterable groups of rows based on some common factor (which here in your case is product_id) It will make small groups of rows having same product_id. And it will apply aggregation over those only but we know aggregation returns a single value and the other columns you are trying to print can not be printed because the are supposed to have multiple values which again can not be printed because one cell contains a single value.(1st Nomal Form).
And comming back to main topic how the hell was it gonna be solved so here is the actual query that may solve the problem:
SELECT s.product_id, s.year AS first_year, s.quantity, s.price
FROM sale s
JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, MIN(year) AS first_year
    FROM sale
    GROUP BY product_id
) t
ON s.product_id = t.product_id AND s.year = t.first_year;

I hope it helps you out, otherwise you can ask me to explain it.

Hi Faraz, Thanks for helping out. Btw my query didn't throw any error as you suggested, it worked fine for one of the one test cases.

Here is the solution:
select product_id, year as first_year, quantity, price from 
(select * from Sales order by year asc limit 100000) as tmp_table group by product_id


sort the data by year(limit is important to sort, the sort is invalid if without the sort)
group by

